# Getting response code 200 in Postman but not on Android Network library

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2, internal-server-error

I have a POST method API which is giving 200 response code in **Postman** but not when calling api by using **Volley** or even in **Retrofit2**.

Here is Postman screenshots:

[image]

Here what i did for **Volley** library code:

```
final String url = "http://xxxxxxxx.com/api/mobile/user/post/";

    StringRequest stringReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("onResponse ===", response + " " );
                }
            },
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("onErrorResponse ===", error + " " );
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("post_body", "test");
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    mApp.addToRequestQueue(stringReq);
    stringReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            REQUEST_TIME,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Error **Logcat:**

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/mobile/user/post/
```

Comment: can you please share your manifest? 
Did you add the following permissions?

"android.permission.INTERNET"
"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

Comment: ya man no doubt on it.

Comment: 500 is a server error. My experience with these situations is usually related with headers. Postman adds by default some headers that retrofit and volley don't. Sometimes the severs can't cope with this lack of headers and throw a500. I'd advise you to check this. It might be the other way around too.

Comment: @Fred you are right. We can get response in iOS as well, but not in Android. Strll i am not getting any solution.

Comment: So what I was suggesting is to verify which headers your Android implementation sends and which ones Postman or iOS sends and find out the one that crashes the server. Once you know that (assuming it's a header) you can add it with retrofit using the ``@HEADER`` annotation or even an ``OkHttp`` interceptor if needed.

Comment: You can get working code from postman as it provide under save button

Comment: Have actually no idea why you're ignoring my answer, seems it solves the problem.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930098/retrofit2-post-method-showing-server-internal-error-but-postman-giving-response/42041502#42041502

Comment: @ErAdhish this is not valid at all as we speak Volley here and with the request he sends contains the content type, however he sends the incorrect one as rom4ek noted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your endpoint assumes `multipart/form-data` request (as orange pin is set to `form-data` radiobutton in Postman), while `Volley`'s default content-type for `StringRequest` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, that's why you get 500 error.

So, if you're only supposed to send POST params in multipart request, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38238994/3225458). But if you want to send files as well, check [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803473/3225458)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, JSONObject, response, error);` for post request it's easy to use try once

Comment: This is not library problem, its headers that your passing and can you check with ION network library for android or check in Postman in response headers it shows 10 while your passing one

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same issue I solved by using

```
 @Override
 public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
  final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
  return headers;
 }
```