# invalid request error when trying to call a JSON api through android

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I am trying to call an API through android it is giving invalid request error.

while API giving the correct result in POSTMAN.

I am using the following code . Is something wrong in following code.

```
 String url ="http://apiaddress";

// POST parameters
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
 params.put("tag", "test");

  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);

// Request a json response from the provided URL
  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
  (Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            System.out.print("JSOn Object:"+jsonObj.toString());
        }
     });
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception ? If yes kindly edit question and  post stack trace from logcat as well. If not, kindly check whether that url is accessible from phone or not.

Comment: Try to check your permission in manifest like internet and all.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935546/getting-response-code-200-in-postman-but-not-on-android-network-library

Comment: System.out.print("JSOn Object:"+jsonObj.toString()); in this line it shows invalid request

Answer (score 0):

In Volley, `JsonObjectRequest` seems not to work for POST requests. Use `StringRequest` instead.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613565/4586742), too.

Also, `override` the `getParams` method of the `StringRequest` and return your params as a `map`.